# Math - Percentage to Range Conversion

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I'm trying to solve a problem where I know a percentage (set by the user) but I need to find where that percentage is on a range of numbers, so for instance if the user sets it to `50%` and the value range is `-10` to `10` the value would be `0`.

It seems simple in my head but I'm tripping up on this one.

Comment: Get the difference between the two numbers to find the size of the range (`20`),  multiply that by `0.5` to get `10` and then add that to the range start of `-10`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maths not programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
pos = low + (high - low) * percentage
```